# is it possible to get mouse event directly without on-mouse in racket?

Tags: functional-programming, mouseevent, racket

I am badly in a need to use mouse-events  directly

Is it possible to get the mouse-event without using big bang ?

i.e I want to build a function like the following:

`(define (check-if-button-down mev) (mouse=? mev "button-down"))`

But for getting mev, the input is being fed from on-mouse of bigbang

About me :
I am new to racket programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not really.

However: the big bang model calls your mouse event handler when a mouse event occurs, so if you want to know whether the mouse button is pressed, your world state should include a boolean indicating whether the mouse button is pressed, and your mouse event handler should return a world state that updates this boolean correctly.

Is there some reason this architecture doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a student project, you may have to stick with what big-bang offers (see John Clements' answer).

But if you can use `racket/gui` (either as a language `#lang racket/gui` or as an additional `(require racket/gui)`), then you are looking for [`get-current-mouse-state`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=get-current-mouse-state#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._get-current-mouse-state%29%29).

For example

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(define (mouse-button-down?)
  (define-values (pt state)
    (get-current-mouse-state))
  (if (or (memq 'left state)
          (memq 'right state)
          (memq 'middle state))
      #t
      #f))
```